# rubyonrails mysql2

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

Hi im just wondering if my configuration of database connection is right

```
development:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  database: db/glob_development
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password: mysql
  host: localhost
  socket: /tmp/mysql.sock
  timeout: 5000
```

because when im trying to run rake:db:create

its goes like this

```
WARNING: This version of mysql2 (0.2.17) isn't compatible with Rails 3.1 as the ActiveRecord adapter was pulled into Rails itself.
WARNING: Please use the 0.3.x (or greater) releases if you plan on using it in Rails >= 3.1.x
DEPRECATION WARNING: Arel::Visitors::VISITORS is deprecated and will be removed. Database adapters should define a visitor_for method which returns the appropriate visitor for the database. For example, MysqlAdapter.visitor_for(pool) returns Arel::Visitors::MySQL.new(pool). (called from mon_synchronize at /home/led/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:201)
db/test.sqlite3 already exists
db/production.sqlite3 already exists
```

im running in fedora15
1.9.2p290 ruby version
rails 3.1.1

**EDIT**

just download mysql2 with and change my gemfile

```
gem 'mysql2', '~>0.3.10'
```

uhm just wondering 
the terminal keep on saying that

```
db/glob_development already exists
db/test.sqlite3 already exists
db/production.sqlite3 already exists
```

but my db folder dosent have glob_development file is it an error or it is natural? sorry guys

Answer (score 1):

When you run `rake db:create`, it's saying it worked and those databases already exist. Check out those db's on MySQL Workbench (or in Command-Line Interface via mysql in the Terminal to check them out).

Run a `rake db:migrate` to update your db.

If you don't see it in your "db" folder, try connecting to your mysql server and checking. Do you have the details about this? It's connecting to your mysql server via the /tmp/mysql.sock.

Check that your username and password connect to the database from mysql (using one of the methods above).

Comment: thanks for the reply it has been their already stupid me :) by the way is my configuration ok? i dont know about /tmp/mysql.sock thingy sorry :(

Comment: Yup. If you have questions about that "...already exists" issue, it should be resolved in Rails 3.1 (https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/899). Just make sure you've got ruby 1.9.2 or ruby 1.9.3, rails 3.1; run "bundle install" to update gems; and make sure any tutorials you're reading reference ruby 1.9 (and not 1.8) if that's your environment

Answer (score -1):

```
rails new project_name
```

The above line creates a new project along with that creates SQLite databases. But if you run

```
rails new project_name -d mysql
```

then the database is not created and you have to run

```
rake db:create
```

Your problem might be related to the adapter, I faced this problem in mac. I had to change adapter option to mysql. Also include mysql gem in Gemfile.

Comment: From the question, it looks like he's aware of the need to run `db:create` so this doesn't seem to address the question very well.